# Tinymcebundle not working with Ajax xhr request

Tags: symfony, tinymce

I am using TinymceBundle with symfony2.1. The plugin work perfectly with any page except Ajax request. I understand that in order for tinymce to work, some javascript need to run to change textarea to wysiwyg. I am using https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle.

Comment: No error. as mentioned, I think TinymceBundle does not handle new added element to dom. I need a way to tell the tinymcebundle the new added element. I prefere the tinymcebundle way. If this can not be done with TinymceBundle, then I have to remove tinymcebundle and use tinymce js natively without the bundle.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to include the `tiny_mce.js`.
Check that this file is loaded on your page.